# How to set proxy for each request in OkHttp?

Tags: java, httpclient, okhttp

I'm building a proxy-like application using `OkHttp`. This application need to forward different request to different proxy.

I didn't find any api in OkHttp to set proxy for one request,
and `ProxySelector` can't solve my problem either because choosing a proxy for request does not only depends on the request's host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `okhttpClient.newBuilder()` to create one client from another, then each client will be very lightweight. They will share the same connection pool and dispatcher, for example. See [OkHttpClient’s docs on sharing](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a pool of OkHttpClients, one for each proxy you need to connect to. When you need to make a request via a proxy, you grab the OkHttpClient set up to use that proxy and use it to make your request (creating the client if necessary).

Depending on how many proxies you need to connect to, you may also want to clear out infrequently used clients to save memory.

Comment: If you use `okhttpClient.newBuilder()` to create one client from another, then each client will be very lightweight. They will share the same connection pool and dispatcher, for example. See [OkHttpClient’s docs on sharing](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html).

Comment: @JesseWilson Please post your answer, I would accept it.